# GD2 and PHP on OS X

Tags: php, macos, gd

There are tons of links on this topic - but all have a different approach. I have a clean install of os x 10.5.6. I'm using the version of PHP that came with the OS.

I have installed GD using FINK, it has installed associated packages. **My question is, how do I now get GD support in PHP?**

*(pref no macports or marc liyanage suggestions as that involves undoing the other installs of pear, mysql and php I have already done)*

Answer (score 4):

As Nerdling points out, PHP must be compiled with the GD extension enabled, therefore there's no *clean* way of adding GD2 to the version of PHP that ships with Mac OS X.

This solution worked for me (Mac OS X 10.5.2, should work with any 10.5), but you'll have to make a new PHP installation. However, **this will not undo your other installs of PEAR and MySQL**, you'll just have to `sudo` one extra line.

Before we start, if you've already enabled the built in PHP, you'll have to re-comment the PHP line (LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so) in (/etc/apache2/)httpd.conf. And now, the steps:

1. In Terminal.app, type `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2 /etc/httpd`
   This makes a symlink so entropy's package can install and function correctly.
2. Download entropy's [PHP 5.2.4 for Apache 2](http://www2.entropy.ch/download/entropy-php-5.2.4-1-apache2.tar.gz) package and install it.
3. Again in Terminal, type:
   `sudo cp /usr/sbin/httpd /usr/sbin/httpd-fat

   sudo lipo /usr/sbin/httpd -thin i386 -output /usr/sbin/httpd`
   This downgrades Apache 2 to 32 bits so it can play nice with entropy's PHP package.
   `sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5 /usr/local/apache2

   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libexpat.dylib /usr/local/apache2/lib/libexpat.0.dylib`
   This fixes a misplaced file.
   `sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php_back

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php`
   This fixes possible errors with PEAR/PHP extensions.
4. Restart Apache (can be done typing `sudo apachectl restart`).

*Some reference: http://www.entropy.ch/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?t=3074*

Answer (score 0):

PHP must be compiled with the GD extension enabled.

You can see what extensions and compile flags were used by using the following PHP code:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```